# DB choice for a live blogging app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm starting to write a live blogging app like "Coveritlive". I need it for my online magazine and I cannot find something ready for Rails. BTW is not important, I will try to write it.

I'm a junior developer, and I already write my CMS. By the way I'm not sure about the stack to use for the live blogging app.

For the CMS I'm using PostgreSQL as db, but I'm not sure if this choice can have some negative impact on the live blogging system. The architecture is easy:

- Every event has many event_post (date, author, content)

On the event page I will have the ordered list of the event_post from the most recent to the oldest one. The content of an event post is an html piece, so text / img / etc etc

An event could have more than 500/ 600 event_post.

Do you think that postgres is ok for this? Have you got any suggestion to have better performance?

When the event is not live people have access to the live feed so I must load all the event in the same page. I'm worried about performance.

For the live update I will use Pusher / Slanger.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with Postgres. It will have the best support for any gems you are using and I can't think of an inherent reason to choose anything else at this point for this project. Performance will be fine.